# Monte Carlo method for calculating poker equities

Tags: c, random, montecarlo, poker

I started to learn C language on my own and decided to build a program that calculates poker equities. I'm trying to calculate equity with Monte Carlo, but I get wrong results.

So here is an example: I'm holding JsTs (Jack of spades and 10 of spades). I have two opponents who I'm assigning specific hand ranges. First opponent plays only with AA (any Ace-Ace pocket, 6 different combinations in total), the second plays with KK+ (any Ace-Ace or King-King pocket). So the calculation process starts by randomly selecting a range from opponent ranges (for opponent 1 this is always AA). Then I'm determining different combos in that range (Ah Ac, Ah Ad, Ah As ... etc) and randomly select one of the combos in the range. So I do this for both opponents. Then I randomly choose five board cards and evaluate player hand and opponent hands. And then I see if I win or tie and keep tally of the results.

So I'm doing this 10 million times and my equity comes 20,5%, but it should be 19,1%. Here is the main() function of my code:

```
int main()
{
randctx rctx;
Deck[4][13];
randinit(&rctx, TRUE);
numberOfOpponents = 2;

//opponent ranges selected
rangeIsSelected[0][0]= 1;
rangeIsSelected[1][0]= 1;
rangeIsSelected[1][14]= 1;

//player cards
Player_Card_Flush[0] = 0;
Player_Card_Rank[0] = 8;
Player_Card_Flush[1] = 0;
Player_Card_Rank[1] = 9;

//insert player cards to dealt cards
Deck[Player_Card_Flush[0]][Player_Card_Rank[0]] = 1;
Deck[Player_Card_Flush[1]][Player_Card_Rank[1]] = 1;

checkForErrors(0);

if (impossibleError==1) {
    printf("Impossible to calculate equity");
    return;
}

gamesSimulated = 0;
totalTies = 0;
totalWins = 0;
int opponentToBeDealt = 0;

//let's see what ranges are selected by opponents
for (int i=0; i<numberOfOpponents; i++) {
    findSelectedRanges(i);
}

//beginning of Monte Carlo method
while (gamesSimulated<maxTrials) {
    int b = 0;
    int opponentsDealt = 0;

    //randomly select hand for opponents
    while (opponentsDealt<numberOfOpponents) {

        opponentCardsForMonteCarlo(opponentToBeDealt);

        opponentsDealt += 1;

        if (opponentsDealt==numberOfOpponents) break;
        if (opponentToBeDealt==numberOfOpponents-1) {
            opponentToBeDealt = 0;
        }
        else {
            opponentToBeDealt += 1;
        }
    }

    //randomly choose 5 board cards
    while (b<5) {

        int randomCardTag = rand(&rctx) % 52;

        randomCardFlush[b] = randomCardTag / 13;
        randomCardRank[b] = randomCardTag % 13;

        //if this card hasn't been dealt then add to dealt cards
        if (Deck[randomCardFlush[b]][randomCardRank[b]]==0) {
            Deck[randomCardFlush[b]][randomCardRank[b]] = 1;
            b++;
        }
    }

    //evaluate hands (this function also removes random opponent hands when it's done)
    calculateMonteCarloEquity();

    //remove random board cards from dealt cards
    for (int x=0; x<b; x++){
        Deck[randomCardFlush[x]][randomCardRank[x]]=0;
    }
}
```

Because I have written my own evaluation code I suspected that first, but when I do exhaustive enumeration with the exact same code I get correct results (confirmed with PokerStove). Then I started to look if there's any bias in the way I deal the cards for my opponents. This is my output:

***Opponent 1 hands***
As Ac: 1665806 times
As Ah: 1667998 times
As Ad: 1666631 times
Ac Ah: 1665767 times
Ac Ad: 1666595 times
Ah Ad: 1667203 times

***Opponent 2 hands***
As Ac:  833847 times
As Ah:  833392 times
As Ad:  832396 times
Ac Ah:  833406 times
Ac Ad:  834542 times
Ah Ad:  833703 times
Ks Kc:  832585 times
Ks Kh:  835641 times
Ks Kd:  832483 times
Kc Kh:  833013 times
Kc Kd:  831558 times
Kh Kd:  833434 times

This looks pretty random to me. I also looked at the board cards and there doesn't seem to be any bias also, basically all cards are dealt approximately 1,08xxxx million times except As - 271 812 times, Ac - 272 856 times, Ah - 271 898 times, Ad - 272 062 times, Ks - 815 113, Kc - 816 871, Kh - 814 955 times, Kd - 814 866 times and of course Js - 0 times and Ts - 0 times. I also tried to create an array of undealt cards so my random board card won't be rand(&rctx) % 52, but depending on the situation rand(&rctx) % 46, rand(&rctx) % 45 etc (basically I only choose from undealt cards). However this doesn't change the results very much.

I'm using ISAAC random number generator, although I almost get the same result with the built-in rand() function. I've tried to seed it with time like so `randinit(&rctx, time(NULL))` but not much difference in end results. Yeah, I know time is a bad seed for cryptographic purposes, but should be OK for simulations like this one.

So I've run out of ideas, maybe someone can see something that I am missing?

***Edit***
Here's my equity calculation code

```
void calculateMonteCarloEquity() {
opponentsBeaten = 0;
opponentsTied = 0;
opponentsLost = 0;

//remove all opponent cards from dealt cards, because we need 7 dealt cards to evaluate hand
for (int x=0; x<numberOfOpponents; x++) {
    Deck[opponentCardFlush[x][0]][opponentCardRank[x][0]] = 0;
    Deck[opponentCardFlush[x][1]][opponentCardRank[x][1]] = 0;
}

//at this point we have 5 board cards and 2 player cards left in dealt cards
//so let's evaluate that hand
Evaluate_Hand();
playerHandScore = Hand_Score;

//now remove player hand form dealt cards
Deck[Player_Card_Flush[0]][Player_Card_Rank[0]] = 0;
Deck[Player_Card_Flush[1]][Player_Card_Rank[1]] = 0;

//let's evaluate opponent hands and save their scores
for (int x=0; x<numberOfOpponents; x++) {

    //insert opponent x hand to dealt cards
    Deck[opponentCardFlush[x][0]][opponentCardRank[x][0]] = 1;
    Deck[opponentCardFlush[x][1]][opponentCardRank[x][1]] = 1;

    Evaluate_Hand();
    opponentHandScore[x] = Hand_Score;

    //remove opponent x hand from dealt cards when evaluated
    Deck[opponentCardFlush[x][0]][opponentCardRank[x][0]] = 0;
    Deck[opponentCardFlush[x][1]][opponentCardRank[x][1]] = 0;
}

//compare  opponent hand scores with player hand score
for (int x=0; x<numberOfOpponents; x++) {

    if (playerHandScore > opponentHandScore[x]) {
        opponentsBeaten += 1;
        continue;
    }
    else if (playerHandScore == opponentHandScore[x]) {
        opponentsTied += 1;
        continue;
    }
    else if (playerHandScore < opponentHandScore[x]) {
        opponentsLost += 1;
        continue;
    }
}

//if player beats all opponents he wins the hand
if (opponentsBeaten==numberOfOpponents) {
    totalWins += 1;
}
//if player doesn't beat all the opponents, but neither loses to anyone, there must be a tie
if (opponentsLost==0 && opponentsBeaten!=numberOfOpponents) {
    totalTies += 1/(opponentsTied+1);
}

//one game has been evaluated
gamesSimulated += 1;
playerEquity = (totalWins+totalTies)/gamesSimulated;

//let's insert player cards back to dealt cards
Deck[Player_Card_Flush[0]][Player_Card_Rank[0]] = 1;
Deck[Player_Card_Flush[1]][Player_Card_Rank[1]] = 1;

if (gamesSimulated>=maxTrials) return;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your calculation for the 19,1%. Have you factored in that the opponents will always have kings and aces? That means that the probability of getting jacks and tens on the table are based on 46 cards and not 50 cards.

Comment: Have you done a statistical analysis of your result? What is the probabiliy of getting 20.5% if the correct value is 19.1%?

Comment: I still think that the theoretical value (the 19.1%) may be wrong. How did you arrive at 19.1%?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck You can see it from PokerStove or when I do exhaustive enumeration (e.g. calculate every possible combination there is). With Monte Carlo the result should converge to the exhaustive enumeration result and pretty fast. With a million tries it already should be 19,1%.

Comment: You have assigned equal probability for AA and KK for opponent 2. Is 19,1% the mean of the probability of winning against AA AA and against AA KK? (Because in real life, AA KK is more probable than AA AA)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It would be a good idea for deville to report results as a confidence interval rather than as a point estimate, but we can easily evaluate whether his result is plausible relative to `p=0.191`.  Standard error is `sqrt(p * (1-p) / n)`. Given his sample size, if he's right about `p` then 0.205 is 11262 standard errors away from 0.191.  I'd call that a significant difference.

Comment: Just as an aside: I'm curious how your hand evaluator stacks up against mine: http://github.com/lcrocker/ojcardlib

Comment: @KlasLindbäck was right. I didn't take into account the number of combinations so AA KK is more probable than AA AA. So basically I skipped the step where I was choosing a random range and instead looked at every possible combination my opponent could have. So for example when first opponent has been dealt AsAc, then opponent 2 has these possible combinations: AdAh,KsKc,KsKh,KsKd,KcKh,KcKd,KhKd. Now I randomly choose one of them and so it is guaranteed that AA AA comes up less than AA KK and I get the 19,1% equity. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have assigned equal probability for AA and KK for opponent 2.

In real life, AA KK is more probable than AA AA. There are 6 kombinations with KK and only one with AA.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is your problem for this particular application, but this is a bad way to use RNG's with Monte Carlo methods:

```
int randomCardTag = rand(&rctx) % 52;
```

because of two reasons:

1. the low bits aren't very random - with the modulus operator you are discarding all the good high bits. Randomness is created mostly by carries in most generators (for sure by LCG's, as rand() in most (all?) implementations).
2. the number of states for different randomCardTag's is different: the RNG has RAND_MAX+1 states and except RAND_MAX+1 is multiple of 52, some randomCardTag's have 1 more state. That's a tiny difference, in the order of 1/(RAND_MAX/52), but often RAND_MAX is not big for this generator.

The correct way to use it should rather be with division:

```
int randomCardTag = rand(&rctx) / (RAND_MAX/52);
```

Note that you must use it in this way so the number of states of the RNG is the same for each randomCardTag, despite the presence of a reminder. However there are some states leading to randomCardTag = 52, so:

```
int randomCardTag;
do {
  randomCardTag = rand(&rctx) / (RAND_MAX/52);
} while (randomCardTag > 51);
```

I would use a Mersenne-Twister RNG however, just to be sure you are not encountering some correlation with rand().

If you still have the problem after these fixes, than there's another problem elsewhere.